# Can/should I migrate my own questions, or should I just delete them and re-ask?

Tags: discussion, migration, vote-to-close

I asked a question and after a second realized it was better for programmers, so I deleted it and then asked it on programmers. Would it have been better to vote to migrate it or is it irrelevant? The question is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/78523/4553).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends I guess. If you see that early, delete it. If you waited some time, migration will be better as it will leave a trace on SO for followers to find the new question.

If it is already answered : migration is mandatory so as not to lose the answer.